# Extend isomorphism of subgroups to homomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given two finite groups $G_1$ ang $G_2$ with respective subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ satisfying $H_1\cong H_2$ via the isomorphism $\phi$, is it always possible to extend $\phi$ to an homomorphism $\bar\phi:G_1\to G_2$? i.e. is it possible to construct a morphism $\bar\phi:G_1\to G_2$ with $\bar\phi(x)=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in H_1$?

Comment: Even for abelian groups $G_1=G_2$ and $H_1=H_2$ the homomorphism does not have to exist: Take the direct product $C_2\times C_4$ of two cyclic groups of orders $2$ and $4$ and its subgroup isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$ of elements whose squares are $1$. An automorphism of $C_2\times C_2$ exchanging the element of order $2$ in $C_4$ with any other element of order $2$ can not be extended.

Answer (score 6):

Take the two alternating groups $A_n,\  A_m$ with $m,n \ge5,\, m > n$. Both of them contain elements of order $5$, and hence we have subgroups $H_1\subset A_m$ and $H_2\subset A_n$ of order $5$ in them that are isomorphic (e.g., they could be the subgroups generated by $5$-cycles).

But we cannot  find a homomorphism $A_m\to A_n$ extending this isomorphism of $H_1$ with $H_2$: it cannot be trivial as the image has to contain $H_2$, and it cannot  be injective as $A_m$ has order bigger than $A_n$. There are no other normal subgroups ($A_m$ is  simple), hence  there is no candidate for the kernel for any intended extended homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $G_1$ be any simple nonabelian finite group and $H_1$ a proper nontrivial subgroup, and then define $G_2=H_2\cong H_1$. Our putative map $\tau:G_1\to G_2$ cannot be the trivial map as it restricts to the isomorphism $H_1\to H_2$, but $\tau$ must have nontrivial kernel since $|G_1|>|G_2|$. Kernels are normal subgroups and this contradicts the hypothesis that $G_1$ is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another counter example with $G_2$ abelian, and $G_1$ not simple. Take $G_2$ as  Klein's 4-group and  $G_1$ to be $S_n$ with $n>4$.
As we can find in $G_1$ two transpositions $\tau, \tau'$ operating on disjoint subsets the subgroup generated by them is ismorphic to the Klein's group, $G_2$.

As $S_n$ does not have a normal subgroup of index 4, the isomorphism of these two Klein's groups cannot be extended to whole of $S_n$ as a homomorphism.